# How to send an Email in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

so here is my code:

```
   protected void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("Kamal.s.buqlieh@hotmail.com","Kamal");
        msg.To.Add(TxtEmailPass.Text);
        msg.Subject = "Forget Password!";
        msg.Body = "your password is:";
        SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mySmtpClient.Host = "www.Hotmail.com";
        NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();
        nc.UserName = "Kamal.s.buqlieh@hotmail.com";
        nc.Password = "";
        mySmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        mySmtpClient.Credentials = nc;
        mySmtpClient.Port = 587;
        mySmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        mySmtpClient.Send(msg);


    }
```

it keeps telling me that

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 157.56.198.204:587"

anyone can help me with this?

Comment: IMHO Either there is a firewall blocking the connection or the process that is hosting the service is not listening on that port, this may be because it is not running at all or because it is listening on a different port.

Answer (score 1):

Your host address is wrong. you have used "www.Hotmail.com".

```
mySmtpClient.Host = "www.Hotmail.com";
```

Try this SMTP settings for your Hotmail account:

- **Hotmail SMTP server name:** smtp.live.com
- **Hotmail SMTP port:** 25 or 465

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft Outlook & the Outlook Connector, you can define your Hotmail account just like any regular POP3 email account:

```
Hotmail Incoming Mail Server (POP3) - pop3.live.com (logon using Secure Password Authentification - SPA, mail server port: 995)

Hotmail Outgoing Mail Server (SMTP) - smtp.live.com (TLS enabled, port 587)
```

See  [Incoming and Outgoing Mail Server Settings for Hotmail, Yahoo! Mail, GMail, MSN, AOL and more](http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html)